# Jquery UI not working properly for some words

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#customers" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'search.php'
});
});
</script>
<div class="ui-widget"><input id="customers" name="Cno" placeholder="Customer Name"></div>
```

search.php

```
<?php include('header.php');
//get search term
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
//get matched data from skills table
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Customer_Name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY Customer_Name ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
$data[] = $row['Customer_Name'];
}
//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

[image: search from keyword gulf]

[image]
[image]

Please check in first screenshot, Search by Keyword 'gulf' is not showing, But when I search 'gulf r' then it shows data, And I have also attached scrshot of search by keyword 'abd' 3 letters only, Then also it is working properly, But Why is this not working for 'gulf'

Comment: Check developers console for ajax request and it's results.

Comment: Please check this scrshot of console http://prntscr.com/dnn8ka

Comment: json_encode() was not working, I solved it by $mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4') but got another issue, selecting an element from list is taking so much time